# Java program displays the result one less than desired result

Tags: java

I was doing this practice problem on a competitive coding site. WE have a scenario in which we have a smart browser in which we don't need to enter "www." and neither the vowels. The browser enters these two things by its own.

I am writing a program which displays the ratio of the no of characters in the smart web url and the complete web url. ie. for example smart url for `www.google.com` would be `ggl.com`. Hence display of program would be `7/14`. I did that but my display is `6/14`. i.e one less .It is for every test case. I don;t know where is the problem

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();// no of testcases!

    while(t > 0)
    {
        String st = sc.next();
        int count = st.length();
        count = count-4;
        int count1 = st.length();
      for(char da:st.toCharArray())
        {
            switch(da)
            {
                case 'a':
                    count  = count -1;
                    break;

                    case 'e':
                    count = count -1;
                    break;

                    case 'i':
                    count = count-1;
                    break;

                    case 'o':
                    count = count -1;//System.out.println(da);
                    break;

                    case 'u':
                    count = count -1;
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.print((count ) +"/" +count1) ;
        System.out.println();
        t--;

    }
```

Comment: Then set `count` to `count - 3`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That would work for `.com` urls but not for `.edu` URLs.

Comment: If the decrement of `count` is the only thing you will do in case of a vowel, you can put mutiple case statements after an other. So will get rid of the copy-paste-code in your case statements.

Comment: @Eran and even more annoying '.co.uk'

Comment: @dwana I didn't consider that. I guess the OP should be more precise regarding which vowels should be dropped and which kept.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan The basic tag is used for the basic programming language, please edit it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ggl.com` still contains a vowel, so your loop would decrement `count` for the `o`, and your program would return 6 instead of 7.

Note that in general, the domain name of the url can have a different number of vowels - for example, `com`, `gov` and `net` have 1, `edu` has 2, `fr` has 0. Your code should ignore the vowels following the last `.`.

This can solve your problem :

```
  ....
  String st = sc.next();
  int count = st.length();
  count = count-4;
  int count1 = st.length();
  st = st.substring(0,st.lastIndexOf('.')); // get rid of the domain name
  for(char da:st.toCharArray())
      ...
```

This assumes that only the vowels following the last `.` should be kept in the count. If, for example, in a `.co.il` domain you wish to keep both the `o` and the `i` in the count, you will have to change the logic.